# How to bind post data to ng repeat in Angular

Tags: angularjs

```
var app = angular.module("newmodule", []).controller("myController", function ($scope,$http,$log) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/EmployeeDetails",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.employees = response;
                    }) 
                },
                error: function () { alert("failure"); }
            });
    });
```

However data is not getting binded ,though i get the data in response.

```
<div ng-controller="myController" style="margin-top:5%;margin-left:5%">
    <table class="table-responsive table-condensed table-bordered" style="margin-top:3%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
                <td>{{ emp.Id }}</td>
                <td>{{ emp.Name }}</td>
                <td>{{ emp.Company }}</td>
                <td>{{ emp.Locaion }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `$http.get` syntax ?

Comment: yes,but get request is not getting the data,getting some error

Comment: check the console for any errors

Comment: i do get the data without any errors but still not getting bind to ng repeat

Comment: What if you `console.log(response)` in your success callback ?

Answer (score 0):

use `$http` instead of the ajax

```
var app = angular.module("newmodule", []).controller("myController", function($scope, $http, $log) {

    $http({
        url: "/Home/EmployeeDetails",
        method: "GET"
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.employees = response.data;
    }).catch(function(response) {
        alert("failure");
    })
});
```

Comment: your code fines but data is not getting bind in following,no error shown     <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
                    <td>{{ emp.Id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ emp.Name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ emp.Company }}</td>
                    <td>{{ emp.Locaion }}</td>
                </tr>

Comment: add a console to check the data is bind to `$scope.employees`

Comment: no need for `contentType` headers on a GET request...there is no content

Comment: also `response` is not the data

Answer (score 0):

As I can try, both are working. I think your problem is eslewhere ...

```js
"use strict";

angular.module("HttpDemo", [])
  .controller("HttpDemo", MainController);

function MainController($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("https://jmgen.herokuapp.com/")
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.httpResult = response.data;
  })
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://jmgen.herokuapp.com/",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      $scope.ajaxResult = response;
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("failure"); }
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="HttpDemo" ng-controller="HttpDemo">
  $http: {{httpResult | json}}<br />
  $.ajax: {{ajaxResult | json}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try to put ng-repeat into the tbody like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="emp in employees">
```

`

Answer (score 0):

use $http service instead of $ajax . and also print the response on console by console.log(response) ;
and study the structure of response because response have two key "meta" and "data". by printing response on console you will find where your data is .
e.g, normally data is present under data key. so try "employees = response.data" .